# How to send a Unicode character with Autokey keyboard.sendkeys()?

Tags: python, unicode, keyboard, autokey

I am trying to use Autokey-py3 v0.93.10 (in Linux Mint 18.2), to generate Unicode characters using the `keyboard.send_keys` command. Unfortunately none of the following attempts work.

```
keyboard.sendkeys("—")
keyboard.sendkeys(u"\u2014")
```

or this attempt copied from unicode.py:

```
import.paste_character("—")
```

Can someone advise me what I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me (mostly):

```
keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+<shift>+u+" + "012b")
keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>")
```

It seems to depend on the app you are writing to, the desktop environment, the distro and the version thereof...

For example, it is working now in this window - but it's not working inside LibreOffice Writer on KDE/Manjaro (although it was working there a few months ago).

Comment: vivasteve, <brilliant> + <thank you>. it works where I need it, on editing text pages on Wikipedia.

Comment: check this post for an alternative method using phrases: https://brushingupscience.wordpress.com/2015/12/28/add-any-symbol-without-leaving-the-keyboard/                                                                  also works in libre writer - nice!

Comment: again thanks. It never occurred to me to try a script and assigned a key to it. In Windows I use Autohotkey extensively, it is a well documented and a superb keyboard app.

Comment: agreed about autohotkey - but autokey is also a great app - documentation, not so good! And it's really great that we still have maintainers of the project - kudos

Comment: What is the need to send <ctrl>? This seems to be needed. Both with and without that 2nd line, I experience inconsistencies

Comment: @Cyriac Ctrl seems to terminate the Unicode sequence. Enter, Shift, and Space also work.

Comment: Please see [this](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Unicode-Characters) which details how it works. I don't understand why we need a character after the Unicode spec, but we do. It seems like a delimiter so it gets parsed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the replies. Since this was posted this issue was resolved.
I am using LMC 20.3 and Autokey 96.10beta, and either of the following are functioning as they should.

```
keyboard.sendkeys("—")
keyboard.sendkeys(u"\u2014")
```